# Read output from a Python command in a PHP webapp

Tags: php, python, shell-exec

I'm trying to read python output from a php webapp.

I'm using `$out = shell_exec("./mytest")` in the php code to launch the application, and `sys.exit("returnvalue")` in the python application to return the value.

The problem is that `$out` doesn't contain my return value.
Instead if I try with `$out = shell_exec("ls")`, `$out` variable contain the output of `ls` command.

If I run `./mytest` from terminal it works and I can see the output on my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```
sys.exit("returnvalue")
```

Using a string with `sys.exit` is used to indicate an error value. So this will show `returnvalue` in `stderr`, not `stdout`. `shell_exec()` only captures `stdout` by default.

You probably want to use this in your Python code:

```
print("returnvalue")
sys.exit(0)
```

Alternatively, you could also use this in your PHP code to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

```
$out = shell_exec("./mytest 2>&1");
```

(In fact, doing *both* is probably best, since having `stderr` disappear can be quite confusing if something unexpected happens).

Comment: print("returnvalue")
sys.exit(0)
doesn't works...$out = shell_exec("./mytest 2>&1") works but it returned only the last line, and, unfortunately, panda3d add 2 messages lines after my return value...

Comment: @stafanovinci I don't know your Python code, or your PHP code for that matter. I can't point out any errors in code I don't know about ;-). This is the error in the code that *you posted*...